# Remove server side validation and make a full blown client side validation?

Tags: javascript, validation, optimization, client-side, server-side

Is it recommended to make all the necessary input validations in client side? I want to optimize the processing of the server (meaning lesser double validation so that the programmer may focus only to business logic).

Example:

- On the client side, there's an 'Age' input `textfield` (`JavaScript` will not allow to submit the form unless it's within the range)
- On the server side, there's no more validation of the 'Age'

  // instead of validating again the age

  int age = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("age"));
  // check age if valid

  if(age >= 0 ) { /* codes * / }

We can instead proceed only to

```
int age = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("age"));
```

because we are very sure that it is valid.

To accommodate disabled `JavaScripts` in Web browsers, we need to check first. If `JavaScript` is enabled, proceed to the application, otherwise block the application. (Just like Facebook)

Is my theory / concept acceptable?

Comment: _"because we are very sure that it is valid."_ -- You can never be sure, you always have to validate on the server.

Comment: "I want to optimize the processing of the server" - what you really mean is "I don't want to do the same work twice." I know the feel, I've been there. There is still no way around server-side validation for important and security sensitive data, however. Any data on client side can be forged.

Comment: One of the major advantage in using client side validation is that it "avoids page post back". This was very relevant in older days where AJAX was less popular. Even with AJAX, client side validation gives faster response and better user experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to enforce certain input patterns, you cannot rely on data that comes from the client.  Folks can disable JavaScript, or simply bypass your validation completely and send whatever data they want.  However, most casual users will not have this problem, and the data is coming from the client anyway.

In short, **it depends**.

For most of my applications, I have client-side validation and only worry about some things server-side that can throw an error condition.  For example, if I have a form that sends an e-mail to someone, I will have JavaScript that checks for a valid `to:` e-mail address, and alert the user.  Server-side, if that e-mail address isn't valid or isn't present, I will simply throw an error writing code to let the user nicely know something has gone wrong.  For the message body, I'll validate client-side whether or not it has one, but server side I won't really care.  Again, what you do depends on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If security / data integrity is a concern, I would advise against this.  While it'll be enough to prevent Joe Smith from entering unwanted data, you'll leave your system open to serious data manipulation from people who understand how the web works.

Let's say you have a voting system like on StackOverflow where anytime a user votes, an AJAX call is made.  While the JS validation may prevent a person from using the displayed HTML to cast multiple votes on the same question or answer, it will not prevent a user from going into their browser's console and manually submitting POST or GET requests to get around the JS validation.  Before you know it, you'll see Lloyd Banks with 100k reputation after answering just a few questions

Answer (score 0):

I believe in validation EVERYWHERE

**I like to have client side validation for:**

- required fields populated
- minimum size fields (like zip)
- Regex for proper character types in proper locations (eg social security numbers, new passwords, etc)
- privilege enforcement (users can only see and do what their role should be allowed to)

**Server Side validation for:**

- all client side requirements
- entity associations (child-parent relationships are legit)
- changes or requests are Role-Authorized

User Entry is the enemy! Users will find a way to break your site willingly or un-willingly. Things will fall through the cracks. **So I strongly endorse double and triple checking.**

I would believe in client side validation to save server processing, if it NOT for my fear that this kind of thinking will make me exceptions more prominent.

**Overall, the reasons why I value rich Client side validation are:**

- one more level of checking data integrity (as well as server side)
- guiding users; intelligent client side validation makes helps users make more efficient answers quicker
- a better experience; If users don't have to wait for the loop back to server and returned to client to see their errors, their user experience should be better.